# Lodash library outside module. Crashes app whenever imported

Tags: javascript, lodash

```js
import _ from 'lodash';

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.js" ></script>
    <script type="module" src="./script.js" defer></script>
    <title>Quiz</title>
</head>
```

I get this error code in the console whenever I try to import lodash and my whole program stops working.
*Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module*

Comment: Is that a js file? ts file? Do you have more information?

Comment: its. js file, linked to index.html

Comment: Put an attribute `type="module"` for the script tag on the HTML file

Comment: ok so I did and it gave me "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "lodash". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"."

Comment: post the HTML file

Comment: just posted the html head

Comment: Put your scripts in the bottom of the `<body>`

Comment: AND change the import to:
const _ = require('lodash')

Comment: Thank u for your time first of all, and secondly, that's what I started with but it gives me the error require not defined and offers quick fix that makes it into "import _ from 'lodash';"

Comment: I would have try to save the CDN file locally instead of getting it by URL, that should solve the problem

Comment: could you provide an example on how?

Comment: Open the URL for the lodash lib, save it to your local repo, import by navigate to the right path